# How to position fixed when using float and div?

Tags: html, css

I am using:

```
 <div class="class1">Image</div>
 <div class="class2">Image</div>
 <div class="class3">Image</div>
 <div class="class4">Image</div>
```

I am using images as background which should all be in the same line (all images).
I am using `float:left` in which two images will be `float:right`.
But my problem starts when the browser is resizing. All the images will be disordered in different lines.

Any help is appreaciated.

Comment: Plz help us. Post some more code. What is the html around? What is your css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear.

If you are wanting all four divs (and why are you using a div instead of an <img>?) to stay in a row, and not wrap onto the line below if the browser window is too small, then you could try (assuming an image width of 200px - using a style instead of a class for simplicity - this is not suitable for deployment!):

```
<div style="width:800px">
  <div class="class1">Image</div>
  <div class="class2">Image</div>
  <div class="class3">Image</div>
  <div class="class4">Image</div>
</div>
```

This will force the container div to be wide enough to contain all four images in a row.  However, if the browser isn't wide enough to show them, you will get a horizontal scroll bar (which is not good from a User Experience point of view)

Alternatively, use your current HTML, and just float all of them left.  If the browser window is resized, then the last image will drop onto the next row, and the divs should remain in the same order

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you define **min-width** to there parent DIV.

For example write like this:

```
.parent{
    overflow:hidden;
    min-width:800px;
}
.parent > div{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}
.class1,.class2{float:left}
.class3,.class4{float:right}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/nRhed/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. As far as I understood it. Check these properties `max-width`,`min-width`, `max-height` and `min-height`. These properties are friends forever to a web designer because these will keep web layout steady. [click here to learn more about them.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/max-width). If we give answer to you, you will not understand the deep concept of their use.
Try to give close values to max and min properties.